# Django ZIP multiple images for download

Tags: python, django, zip

I'm trying to zip several images in a ZIP file.

Although It's a Django app, files are not stored in the same app. I want to fetch them from a url list.

I get the following error: `FileNotFoundError [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'image1.jpg'`

```
def download_image(request):
    fotos = ['https://storage.googleapis.com/some/image1.jpg', 'https://storage.googleapis.com/some/image2.jpg']

    f = StringIO()
    zip = ZipFile(f, 'w')

    for foto in fotos:
        url = urlopen(foto)
        filename = str(foto).split('/')[-1]
        zip.write(filename, url.read())

    zip.close()
    response = HttpResponse(f.getvalue(), content_type="application/zip")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=image-test.zip'

    return response
```

I reviewed several posts and finaly followed this one [how can I export multiple images using zipfile and urllib2 - django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044793/how-can-i-export-multiple-images-using-zipfile-and-urllib2-django)

But I can't get this working. Any clues welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Per [the `zip` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write), `write()` is used to write an existing file into the filesystem (by path). I think that you are looking for [`writestr()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr), which can be passed the actual file contents.